# Accessing chain code containers created using Composer via GOLang API's

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Using composer network, I was able to successfully deploy/start chaincode containers. I am able to access the same using composer-rest-server.

Is it possible to access the container using GOLANG or NODE SDK. The reason for this request is - I came to know that in composer connection profile, one can only mention one channel. I have multiple channel scenario and it will be a overkill to specify multiple REST end points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer will be introducing multiple channel support over time. In the interim, basically, yes - once you have deployed a Composer BNA you do not have to access via Composer. It is possible to access the Composer-generated chaincode (via the peer node).